# Как парсить Ютуб трансляции?

Tags: python, парсер

Всем добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста, хочу парсить ютуб на Python. Парсить прямые трансляции, название трансляции, название канала, который проводит трансляцию и кол-во подписчиков. Вот зашел на ютуб, вижу вкладки "трансляции", но там почему-то всего лишь 100 трансляций, иностранных трансляций там даже нет. Подскажите, где можно на ютубе найти список всех трансляций на данный момент? Заранее большое спасибо!

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLU12uITxBEPFb0yuTkLH2tu8j5SVx1YaA

Comment: Казалось бы, причем здесь python?

Comment: для того, чтобы парсить саму трансу, а именно: название, канал и подписчиков

Comment: но как мне найти список всех трансляций на ютубе на данный момент? ВСЕХ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, чтобы получить название всех трансляций:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r  = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLU12uITxBEPFb0yuTkLH2tu8j5SVx1YaA")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
tmp = soup.find_all('a', class_="pl-video-title-link yt-uix-tile-link yt-uix-sessionlink spf-link ")
for a in tmp:
  print(a.text)
```

Вывод:

```
   [ST.] Субботний стрим #5 ФЕРМА ОПЫТА


  Маша и Медведь -  Если хочешь быть здоров!  ⚽


  #ОставайсяДома - Сериалы Сваты и Байки Митяя - Все серии подряд


   Губка Боб Квадратные Штаны | Снова Полные Эпизоды! | Nickelodeon Россия


  СТРИМ BRAWL STARS ФАНИМCЯ и ПРОХОДИМ КВЕСТ БОЙ С БОССОМ


  Мастер-класс "Уроки кармы" 16 мая 14:00


  Dan Morehead Pantera Capital Live : Bitcoin Halving, BTC Updates, Pantera Capital invests
```

Для выбора меток, распечатайте себе `soup`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо Вам за ответы.

Comment: Скажите, а это вообще единственная ссылка, по которой можно узнать, сколько трансляций есть на ютубе на данный момент?